# Hybris backoffice not loading in Dev Environment

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

We moved hybris 5.2 to 5.6 version for our customer. Now We were not able to access back office site in Dev environment I am getting CMS site not found Error. but hmc and other cockpits are loading fine. I am bale to load back office in my local initially it was not loading due to 2 attributes newly added by hybris in AttributeDescriptor items after adding those attributes it was working fine in local and i did the same changes in dev but still in dev environment i am getting CMS site not found error .. can any one help me on this.?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! This doesn't sound like a programming question, rather, an application configuration question. Try asking this question over at https://serverfault.com/

Answer (score 2):

Have you added the backoffice extension to your `hybris/config/localextensions.xml` ?

If you didn't (maybe due to updating), make sure to add it by adding a new line:

```
<extension name="backoffice"/>
```

Anyways like Tennyson mentioned, this isn't really a programming related question.

Comment: You're right. This should fix the problem. To be sure that everything is fine, we can run `ant clean`, `ant initialize` and `ant all`, to be sure that system is clean and re-initialized. Moreover it's better to ask such questions at experts.hybris.com website.

Answer (score 0):

Add `<extension name="platformbackoffice" />` too to your config/localextensions.xml

or, if the above solution does not work try below one.

Open up orchestrator mode (F4 in BackOffice), then click on the [y] logo in the upper-right corner and choose "Reset everything". The issue was resolved after doing this for 2-3 times.